# Pure CSS tabbed content from fixed HTML

Tags: css

I have some tabs with fixed HTML, which is for use with jquery, but I need a pure css fix if possible for displaying on eBay (client wants to copy HTML content without altering).

So I want the first tabbed content open by default, the rest hidden until the corresponding menu item is clicked (which switches the content).

```
<div id="tabs">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Fourth</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>First content</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Second content</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Third content</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-4">
        <p>Fourth content</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

I can't seem to find a css solution, so putting it out to you, example jsfiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/c3hgy5v2/

Comment: so you want tabs to function like tabs but without jQuery/javaScript and with only pure CSS. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/c3hgy5v2/1/

With `:target` pseudoclass you can show the selected tab, eventually with a basic css transition (e.g. applied to the `opacity`)

Relevant CSS

```
#tabs {
    position: relative;
}

#tabs div {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

#tabs div:target {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Great thanks, I didn't know the target could be used like this. Is there a way to have the first box open by default?

Comment: just add `#tabs-1` as url fragment

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) selector to target the relevant tab and show/hide:

> The `:target` pseudo-class represents the unique element, if any, with
>   an id matching the fragment identifier of the URI of the document..

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3hgy5v2/2/)

```
#tabs ul li {
    display:inline-block;
}
#tabs div {
    display:none;
}
#tabs div:target {
    display:block;
}
```